# Is there a way to add a 'sentiment' column after applying CountVectorizer or TfIdfTransformer to a dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I am working with app store reviews to classify them as class "0" or class "1" based on the text in the review and the sentiment the review carries.

In my classification steps I apply the following methods to my dataframe:

```
def get_sentiment(s):
    vs = analyzer.polarity_scores(s)
    if vs['compound'] >= 0.5:
        return 1
    elif vs['compound'] <= -0.5:
        return -1
    else:
        return 0
```

```
df['sentiment'] = df['review'].apply(get_sentiment)
```

For simplicity sake, the data has already been labeled as either class '0' or '1', but I am training the model for the classification of new instances that have not been labeled yet. In short, the data I'm working with has already been labeled. They are in the `classification` column.

Then in my train test split method do the following:

```
msg_train, msg_test, label_train, label_test = train_test_split(df.drop('classification', axis=1), df['classification'], test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
```

So the dataframe for the X parameter has `review` and `sentiment`, and for the y parameter I only have the `classification` that I am training my model on.

Since the normalization is repetitive, I am running a pipeline like so for simplicity:

```
pipeline1 = Pipeline([
    ('bow', CountVectorizer(analyzer=clean_review)),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
    ('classifier', MultinomialNB())
])
```

Where the `clean_review` function is as follows:

```
def clean_review(sentence):
    no_punc = [c for c in sentence if c not in string.punctuation]
    no_punc = ''.join(no_punc)
    no_stopwords = [w.lower() for w in no_punc.split() if w not in stopwords_set]    
    stemmed_words = [ps.stem(w) for w in no_stopwords]
    return stemmed_words
```

Where stopwords_set is the collection of english stopwords from the `nltk` library, and `ps` is from the `PortStemmer` module in the `nltk` library (for word stemming).

I get the following error: `ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2, 505]`

When I searched this error before, I saw that the likely issue could've been that there is a mismatch in the number of records for each attribute. I've found this not to be the case. All the records that I am using have values for every column.

Can someone else help me interpret what this error could mean?

**My end goal is to have a dataframe that has the CountVectorizer and TfIdfTransformer applied to the text, but also retain the column for the sentiment of each review.**

I would then like to be able to train the MultinomialNB classifier on this dataframe and apply this model to other tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on what the error is due to since I don't know what the size of your dataframe should be. I would need more information. On which line is the error thrown?

Regarding the fact that you want to retain the sentiment column, you could apply CountVectorizer and TfIdfTransformer (by the way you could skip a step and directly apply TfidfVectorizer) only on the text data and then have another transformer in the pipeline which adds the original sentiment column before you feed the dataframe to the classifier.